# Non-existant content in MVC application - what to return to visitor/user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose we have implemented our routes to support URLs as such

```
/content/5
/news/10
```

or maybe we even use slugs. Regardless of what we use as our content identifier, what should the user be returned for non-existant content?

For instance, user requests /news/10 and our controller has this code:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Display(int id, string slug)
    {
    return View(_repository.Find(id));
    }
```

The above will most likely result in an exception when Find() returns null.
What are our options to jump in there and try to solve this issue?

1. do `if..then` check in controller action and direct user to some default page (maybe the entire content list if such a list and view exist),
2. return custom (friendly) 500 result (actually place custom HTTP error handling, so 500 will always redirect to custom friendly page),
3. return custom (friendly) 404 result (similar to option 2 but indicate that the content does not exist)?

We could interpret the error both as being the internal application error or as content not found error. Which one do you think is better to choose?

The same goes for administration pages - what to do there? In this case, I am much more inclined to actually redirect the user to the dashboard or list of content.

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a view like `NewsNotFound` and if your repository returns null, `return View("NewsNotFound", id);` or something similar to that.

You could also do some logging at that point.

For a completely invalid controller/url, just handle that as a regular 404.

Answer (score 1):

How we handle it is that we have three separate views; two views are taken care of by the error handling in the framework (the 404 and 500).

The NoContent view is one that we create outside of `HandleError` (or having the error handling in the `global.asax.cs`, and we normally have a check in our controller for null or zero items in an `IEnumerable<T>` (as the case may be) and if that check is true, we `return View("NoContent");`